# To count no of clicks on hyperlink

Tags: javascript, mysql, html

We want to get the hit counter of an URL link displayed on web browser to be inserted in the database after a timestamp(say 10 minutes)?
e.g 
www.google.com
this is displayed as Hyperlink, want to count the no. of clicks on this after session

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i tried onclick event but how to put the timer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event to click, send an async request to your server, and store it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways this can be done.

Here are a couple that wouldn't be too hard to accomplish:

- Using Jquery/Ajax to capture the click and then insert it into
  thedatabase
- create a redirect page that when clicked on it will log
  the click and redirect to the target page (will hurt your internal links)

Answer (score 0):

Do this

`$('#yourAnchorElement').click(function(){`

```
  $.get('yourAction.action/url');
```

`});`

In your action/ url function just increment the DB value by one on each request

Comment: If you really need a Timer then you can call a DB function from your server which does the update after say 10 mins.